# What is a matching in minimum degree $k$ graph?

Tags: graph-theory, matching-theory

Any graph on $n$ vertices with minimum degree $k$ has a matching of cardinality $\min\{k, \lfloor{\frac{n}{2}\rfloor}\}$.

How to prove this theorem.